# How do I turn off tinyint boolean emulation in Rails 3.2.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

As per the api docs:

If you wish to disable this emulation (which was the default behavior in versions 0.13.1 and earlier) you can add the following line to your application.rb file:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql[2]Adapter.emulate_booleans = false
```

But when I do so, I get:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter
```

Comment: Wild guess: Likely you are putting it in some wrong location because AR has probably not been required at the time.

Comment: I'm putting it in the exact same file the docs are asking me to.

Comment: @Zabba you are right. The docs were wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The docs don't ask you to require activerecord in application.rb. Requiring it solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

For someone see this topic later, I needed to require mysql2_adapter with full path in **Rails 3.2.0**;

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    require 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'
    ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter.emulate_booleans = false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue that I think you had.
But in my case I didn't want to turn off the tinyint emulates but only set some tinyint columns of a legacy database as Integer type and not boolean type.
Searching, I found a solution to my problem. **Matt Jones**¹ showed the Rails code documentation² explaining how to:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    attribute :a_tinyint_1_column_that_isnt_a_boolean, Type::Integer.new
end
```

¹ https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/201859
² https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/daffea59db118fce4247d335eabea026cc54d7bc/activerecord/lib/active_record/attributes.rb#L17

Comment: In Rails 5, I did `attribute :value, ActiveModel::Type::Integer.new`.