# Rails: read integer from tinyint

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a RoR + MySQL setup. In the database there is a Tinyint field *t*. When I read the value of *t* from Rails I get *true* or *false* because a Tinyint field is interpreted by Rails as boolean. So far so good.

How do I read this field *t* as an actual integer from Rails?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to read it as a boolean; I'm surprised that you can't read it as an integer in the same way (it is, after all, a 1-byte integer column).  I don't know if there's a better way in Ruby, but at worst you could try `SELECT CONVERT(tinyintcolumn, [UN]SIGNED) FROM my_table`?

Comment: I just use a standard Model.find_by_id() to fetch the record.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/BeforeTypeCast/attributes_before_type_cast

for instance:

```
Model.first.attributes_before_type_cast['your_boolean_field']
```

It depends on your DB what value will be returned, in postgesql it is 'f' or 't'

Comment: If you only need one field, you can also use the method `read_attribute_before_type_cast('your_boolean_field')` or even `your_boolean_field_before_type_cast`.

Comment: `read_attribute_before_type_cast` doesn't worked for me. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31394926/1154894), you can see how I resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

To build on @sumskyi's response, if you always access this field as a regular integer, you can just override the model's built-in method and save yourself the repetitive motion injury:

```
class GroceryStore < ActiveRecord::Base
  # rating is a TINYINT column
  # we just redefine the method here to return the value cast how we want it
  def rating
    self.attributes_before_type_cast['rating'].to_i
  end
end
```

Now if you call `grocerystore.rating` you'll get an integer instead of a boolean.

Comment: Found some more helpful info [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/AbstractMysqlAdapter/emulate_booleans/class): You can disabled boolean interpretation altogether by setting `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter.emulate_booleans = false` in `config/application.rb`. However, they don't mention that you also have to explicitly require `active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter` in application.rb, so make sure not to miss that! See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038665/how-do-i-turn-off-tinyint-boolean-emulation-in-rails-3-2-2).